# Visual Studio default property sheets not added for 64-bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am performing the following steps in Visual Studio 2010, SP1:

- Create a new, empty Win32 project.
- (now the property manager shows `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` added
- Click Win32 in the tool bar and choose "Configuration manager"
- Active solution platform ->
- Type: x64, copy settings from Win32 and "Create new project platforms" is checked
- Now "Release | x64" appears in the property manager, but `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user` is NOT added.

I am positive the default property sheet `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user` was always added to x64 configurations before. What has happened?

Comment: It doesn't get added either on my machine.  These default property sheets are hum-ho, is this actually a problem?  Post to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but found that after closing and reopening the solution, the default property sheet Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user had been added to the x64 configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the problem that is described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vcgeneral/thread/a724a367-1ed0-4109-a7af-3f4c51c8cab7

And that Microsoft has posted a solution (patch) to here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//gg697159

(At least; I had a similar problem, and this fixed it.)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem after installing VS 2010 SP1. And this fix helped me:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277